# VBA worksheet Tab clean Up

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a workbook with multiple tabs.  I want to clear the slate for each new run.  I have a new tab that I want to eliminate and reset at the new run.  It works for my single listed sheet, but would like to have two listed sheets in the statement.

This is my SQL for the single sheet...

```
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If Sheet.name = "FileNet" Then
          Sheet.Delete
     End If
Next Sheet
```

This is what I'm thinking, but the syntax is off:

```
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If Sheet.name = ("FileNet", "CusReq") Then
          Sheet.Delete
     End If
Next Sheet
```

My end goal is to have both sheets "FileNet" and CusReq" deleted at this point in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line is enough:

```vb
Sheets(Array("FileNet", "CusReq")).Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to iterate between all sheets to delete only two. Please, try the next way:

```
   Dim arrSheets, El
   arrSheets = Array("FileNet", "CusReq")
   For Each El In arrSheets
        Sheets(El).Delete
   Next
```

But both sheets must exist in the workbook. Otherwise, some error handling will be necessary.