# delete sheet using array

Tags: excel, vba

I am working to clean up a workbook and reset all sheets.  I am currently using a delete and add function using an array.  my array is not working in the following vba.

```
shtnm = Array("FileNet", "CusReq", "DocNames")

For Each Shet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sheet.name = shtnm Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets(shtnm).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next Sheet
```

Any insights into how to make this work or a better way to clean up the sheets to no data or formatting is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Loop the array, not the `Worksheets`. As demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68384004/9245853) to your previous question.

Comment: shtnm  is an array not a string, so you need to loop the array's values, but you'll need to handle the sheet not existing before trying the delete.

Comment: Apologies for being an idiot. I do not know how to apply either of the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim Holidays As Variant
Holidays = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet5")

For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    If UBound(Filter(Holidays, Sheet.Name)) > -1 Then
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       Sheet.Delete
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
     
Next
```